# Shell script to check existence of multiple strings in a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have 3 strings

```
A='apples'
B='bananas'
C='carrots'
```

I want to see if all of these exist in the `fruit.txt` file.
If I'm missing `A` then add `A`, `B` then add `B`, and so on.

This is what I have now

```
if grep -qF "$A | $B | $C" fruit.txt;
  then echo 'exist'
else
  echo 'does not exist'
  echo $A $B $C >> fruit.txt
fi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example input and corresponding output for the `if` and `else` cases. Do you want to add a line with all 3 strings if none was found and not add anything if any of the strings was found?

Comment: Your test *as written* will only match literal string `apples | bananas | carrots` - is that what you really want? or are you expecting `|` to act as an alternation operator?

Comment: Are you interested in the occurrences at all, or do you just want to be shure that all fruits are in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of what you want to do contains a description of a loop ("if a string does not exist, add it, repeat for all strings").

You could test the existence of each string individually in a loop, and then add the string if it does not already occur in the file.

```bsh
fruits=( apples bananas carrots )

for fruit in "${fruits[@]}"; do
    if grep -q -wF -e "$fruit" fruit.txt; then
        printf '%s exists\n' "$fruit"
    else
        printf '%s does not exist\n' "$fruit"
        printf '%s\n' "$fruit" >>fruit.txt
    fi
done
```

Here I'm using an array for the strings. If you want to use your `$A`, `$B` and `$C` variables, then either set `fruits=( "$A" "$B" "$C" )` or loop with `for fruit in "$A" "$B" "$C"; do ...; done`.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly answering your question you can do this:

`grep -lr $1 . | xargs -I{} grep -lr $2 {}`

This will find files that contain `$1` AND `$2`